# piping Promise.Parallel

Tags: f#, fable-f#

The result of Promise.Parallel is a single promise which can be access via a let binding. But is there a way to directly pipe that result and get access to it without the let!. I.E. rather than this:

```
promise {
    let! responses = 
        [| "https://somesite.com"               
           "https://somesite2.com"|]
        |> Array.map (fun url -> fetch url [])
        |> Promise.Parallel
    let! results = 
        responses 
        |> Array.map (fun r -> doSomething r))
 }
```

Can I do something like this:

```
promise {
    let! results = 
        [| "https://somesite.com"               
           "https://somesite2.com"|]
        |> Array.map (fun url -> fetch url [])
        |> Promise.Parallel
        |> Promise.Resolve <===== is there such a thing
        |> Array.map (fun r -> doSomething r))
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computation Expressions are an alternative to using the `bind`, `map` functions or their equivalent operators `>>=` and `|>>` respectively.

These operators can be defined like this:

```
let inline (>>=) v f = Promise.bind  f v
let inline (|>>) v f = Promise.map   f v
```

In case `Promise.bind` does not exist then you can define the operators like this instead:

```
let inline (>>=) m f = promise.Bind(m, f)
let inline (|>>) m f = promise.Bind(m, f >> eff.Return)
```

With these operators you can do this:

```
[| "https://somesite.com"               
   "https://somesite2.com" |]
|>  Array.map (fun url -> fetch url [])
|>  Promise.Parallel
|>> Array.map (fun r -> doSomething r)
```

Using the operators there is no need for the CE: `promise {..}`

Comment: Thanks, that works. But not sure it makes it more approachable :)

Comment: Actually, the objective of Computation Expressions is to have a more approachable option than the operator style. The `let!` syntax makes it look more like imperative code.